# cannot import path_provider package

Tags: flutter

I'm building new flutter app, I've downloaded the last version of [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) package, but when I try to import it using the import statement form the docs

```
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
```

It didn't work, it says this package doesn't exist, instead I can import things like

```
import 'package:path_provider_linux/path_provider_linux.dart';
```

which doens't have the functionality I want.

Comment: did you run `flutter pub get`? If yes then restart your editor

Comment: I do all that but nothing works

Answer (score 1):

Can you build the application?
Are you deploying to mobile or MacOS?

Try to run a fresh release configuration, and if it works, then reboot your IDE.
Then run the command that **Confidence Yobo** suggested, to redownload the packages via yaml.

Also make sure that your yaml file is formatted correctly. Once a pubspec **GET** command has finished running and the lock is released, normally if there is an error it will show up on your output window.

Also make sure to get the latest package: **path_provider: ^1.6.18**

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by updating flutter_bloc and bloc packages